# how to filter data with directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use a directive as a filter for my data. This is my data array:

```
$scope.data = [{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "een"
        }, {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "twee"
}];
```

This is my directive filter implemented as a select:

```
.directive('myFilter', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
          var testing = $scope.data | {
            filter: $element.choice
          };
          console.log($element.choice);
          console.log($attributes.choice);
          console.log($scope.choice);
          console.log(testing);
        }
      };
});
```

and templateUrl:

```
<select name="" id="" ng-model='choice'>
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
</select>
```

This is the html where the directive is defined:

```
<my-filter dt="data"></my-filter>
```

plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/zqS5HyH3AqaMVtEv107p?p=preview

How can I change the directive so that when I select 1 in the combo the data is filtered to just 1 record the one with id=1?

Update: I have changed the code slightly trying to filter the $scope.data when I change the value on the combo:

```
  link: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('choice', function() {
                 var testing = $filter('filter')($scope.data,$scope.choice);
                 console.log(testing);
            });
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to fix your filter. Here is the example of right filter:

```
var myRedObjects = $filter('filter')(myObjects, { color: "red" });
```

You can read more about using filters in directives/controllers here: [Using Angular Filters inside the controller](http://voryx.net/using-angularjs-filter-inside-the-controller/)

Second, you must use `$scope.choice` instead of `$element.choice`

Comment: I changed the code slightly but still cant get it to work

Comment: Please, check this version: http://plnkr.co/edit/yjTM5iA6wNLfce75Wvg7?p=preview and open debug console to see console.log

Comment: You can also use it with lambda expression

`var myRedObjects = $filter('filter')(myObjects, (a=>a.color=='red'));`